# Error When Changing UIElements while Multithreading in Swift

Tags: swift

In the following code, I am multithreading my app so that the user can interact with the UI while it also processes data. However, at the end of the Search function which processes data, I set the text of a UITextView to "Complete" but I get the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

---

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(false)

let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), { ()->() in

    self.Search()


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

    })
})


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is precisely because you are updating `UITextView` to "Complete" the app is behaving unpredictably. According to Apple's documentation:

> Threads are tricky to program with in general and, of course, large parts of Cocoa Touch can only be called from the main thread.

Update your "search" function to make sure it doesn't contain any UI updates.